# Opening a div in Facebox programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

Using [Facebox's documentation](http://defunkt.io/facebox/), I'm attempting to pop up Facebox programmatically, with the Facebox content being that of a div that is in the document.

The problem is is that it is not opening with that content - it's opening blank. What am doing wrong? The full code with example is contained in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N4B4v/1/

```
<div id="#TEST10" style="display: none;">
    HEYYYY!
    <br />
    <br />
    heyyyyy!
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery.facebox({ div: '#TEST10' }); return false;"><input type="checkbox" name="AgreeToRequirements" /></a>Open Facebox By Checking The Box
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `id` attribute is wrong. It should be just `TEST10`

Checkout this updated [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/N4B4v/2/)

```
<div id="TEST10" style="display: none;">
    HEYYYY!
    <br />
    <br />
    heyyyyy!
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, literally just saw that. I'm dumb. Dumb mistake. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow requires a certain amount of time (around 15 min) to pass before it lets you accept an answer. I will then.